# Pandas dataframe. Column output value constant for 5 cells, then output changes and remains constant for 5 cells again and so on and so forth

Tags: excel, pandas, if-statement, window-functions, shift

I am very new to python and pandas. Could some kindly help me out with the problem below please?

In Excel I have the following:

[Excel output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bsPRn.png)

```
    MOD(A1,5)+1 Date    Closing Fixed   Percent =IF(B2=5,D2*E2,F3)
0   1   12/05/2020  104.1   1.1 108%    112.4
1   2   11/05/2020  103.5   1.1 109%    112.4
2   3   10/05/2020  100.5   1.1 112%    112.4
3   4   09/05/2020  100.1   1.1 112%    112.4
4   5   08/05/2020  102.2   1.1 110%    112.4
5   1   07/05/2020  102.5   1.1 112%    114.5
6   2   06/05/2020  103.2   1.1 111%    114.5
7   3   05/05/2020  108.7   1.1 105%    114.5
8   4   04/05/2020  106.7   1.1 107%    114.5
9   5   03/05/2020  104.1   1.1 110%    114.5
10  1   02/05/2020  102.1   1.1 118%    120.7
11  2   01/05/2020  102.6   1.1 118%    120.7
12  3   30/04/2020  106.5   1.1 113%    120.7
13  4   29/04/2020  100.5   1.1 120%    120.7
14  5   28/04/2020  109.8   1.1 110%    120.7
```

What is the best way for me to get the output as shown in the final column when I use a dataframe please?

Basically I am taking every 5th closing price * Fixed, with the 1st - 5th cell having the same values.

Cells 6 - 9 will be populated with 9th closing price * Fixed and so and and so forth.

I hope it is clear as the way I am describing it, is very convoluted.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv("D:\<YOUR_DATA>.csv", parse_dates=["Date"])
df_5th = df.loc[df['MOD']==5]
df['blah']=df_5th['Closing'] * df_5th['Fixed']
df['blah']=df['blah'].fillna(method='bfill')
```

Comment: This may be a correct answer, but it’d be useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who may not be familiar with the syntax. Further, it can help reduce the need for follow-up questions. Would you mind updating your comment with additional details?